# How does HTML form know which select option is selected?

Tags: html, forms, html-select

I am trying to understand how the HTML form standard works in relation to select boxes. And the question is how does HTML form know which value a select box has as selected value in order to submit it when the form is submitted. I am inspecting a form with developer tools and I do not see anything changed whenever I change the select box selected option.

This is a pure HTML question and it should be pretty basic for those that they know the HTML standard well. Note that I am not asking for a JavaScript answer on how to get the selected option. I am asking a question in order to understand how does HTML form know which of the options is selected.

If you also have pointers to any documentation, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could ask the same question about how does a form know a checkbox is checked, or what text has been typed into an input field. The HTML for a web page gets parsed into a DOM (Document Object Model), and there are objects behind the scenes representing DOM elements. These objects, among other things, save state information about DOM elements such as selected options and the checking of checkboxes.

Those states don't show up just by viewing the source of a webpage, or necessarily even when using an inspect tool. But the info is there in the DOM for the browser to assemble into the HTTP request that is generated when you submit a form.

Comment: +1 point: in case you want to see the how the state is managed, go to the properties of that element and see there should be some element which has the state of the element. For example: every <option> has a boolean state `selected` as a property.  Similarly for other tags, there are different properties associated which can be examined through developer tools.

Comment: @Vishwaraj Anand, that's why I hedged my wording a bit by saying "necessarily even" -- I thought maybe somewhere, if I looked, I might find tools to do that. But when I inspected a `<select>` element using either Firefox's or Chrome's built-in tools, I couldn't see anything to show which option was selected, not unless there was active JavaScript changing classes of elements when a selection was made.